# Is the RS485 common mode output voltage supposed to be only 3v

Tags: rs485

I am designing an RS485 driver to connect to an ESP32 using SP3485 from Max Linear. I understand that the differential output is 3v and not +7v and -5v like the RS485 spec stipulates. Are there some drivers that achieve +7v and -5v output from a single 3.3v supply, or do they require dedicated power supply eg +12v,-12v to achieve this?

Comment: Lol, they seriously changed their name to "Max Linear"? That's hilarious! (Nothing wrong with these particular parts though, it's the old Sipex ones, the company changes name once every year or so.)

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing separate things.

Differential voltage is voltage between A and B, which can be + or - 3.3V because this a 3.3V that can drive A and B with 0V or 3.3V. A 5V chip would have +/-5V differential output. So the A or B wires are never driven with +7V or -5V.

The +7 and -5 is the common mode voltage tolerance. In fact that is quoted wrong as common mode range of RS485 is required to be -7V to +12V, which means that a 5V powered chips can still communicate if there is up to +/-7V voltage difference between grounds of two chips, so that a 0V/5V signal on transmitter A wire is actually +5V/+12V signal or a -7V/-2V signal on receiver A wire. So it allows +/-7V on top of the 0V-5V signal range.

So a RS485 tranceiver simply needs a single 5V or 3.3V supply to operate, no negative voltages.

Comment: This is the clearest answer I found . What I'm curious about here is that both the driver and the recevier use rs485 transceiver chips. And when I look at the product list in Texas instruments, the voltage operating range is +5 volts and 3.3 V. When does this +12 -7 Volt common mode voltage situation occur? Is there an application for this?

Comment: @Electronx There is no application, the specs just require you have to allow +/- 7 V difference between devices if there are problems. The ideal case is of course that the devices are all wires together with 0 ohm cables and there will be 0V between devices so no margin is needed. So it allows for non-ideal wiring between devices, with ground loop currents flowing between devices so they are not at equal potential.